# Slick inSetBind or inSet doesn't work

Tags: scala, h2, slick, for-comprehension

I'm trying to limit the results of a Slick 3.1.0 query using inSetBind and always get an empty set back. 
Here is the setup:

```
case class VTag(tagID: Option[Long], kind: String, name: String) {
    def toUITag = UITag(tagID = tagID.get, kind = kind, name = name)
}

class VTags(tag: Tag) extends Table[VTag](tag, TagsDao.tableName) {
    def tagID = column[Long]("ID", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
    def name = column[String]("name")
    def kind = column[String]("kind")        
    def * = (tagID.?, name, kind) <>((VTag.apply _).tupled, VTag.unapply)
}


object TagsDao extends SurgeonsTableObject {
    val tableVTags = TableQuery[VTags]
    val db = GlobalDAO.db

    override def tableName: String = "VTAGS"
    override def tableSchema: H2Driver.DDL = tableVTags.schema

    def getTagsByName(tagsToSearch: Set[String]): Future[Seq[VTag]] = {
        val tagList: List[String] = tagsToSearch.toList
        val q = for (c <- tableVTags if c.name.inSetBind(tagList)) yield c
        db.run(q.result)
    }

    def all: Future[Seq[VTag]] = {
        val q = for (c <- tableVTags.sortBy(_.tagID.asc)) yield c
        db.run(q.result)
    }
}
```

*getTagsByName* is the method that creates problem. All return all 100 tags I insert there. *getTagsByName* return always zero. I've tried using inSet / inSetBind, passing as input a list(tagList) or a set (tagsToSearch). Always empty result set. What's going on.
Please don't tell me I have to write SQL ...

Comment: Your example is not [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so I can't run and debug it. Your query is perfectly reasonable. Moreover, I plugged it in Slick example code and it worked fine. Can you post a MCVE somewhere, like Github?

Comment: I've tried to print the SQL STATEMENT to see what happens.

`Logger.info("TAGS_TO_SEARCH: " + tagsToSearch)`
`Logger.info("STATEMENT: " + q.result.statements.head)`


What I get is :
`TAGS_TO_SEARCH: Set(name, my)`
`STATEMENT: select "ID", "name", "kind" from "VTAGS" where "name" in (?, ?)`

So the values of the set don't get injected in the query at all. I've also tried with List or Seq but same result.
Does this help a bit ?

Comment: @AnnaZubenko I've created this gist which mimic the reported behaviour: [MCVE gist](https://gist.github.com/vicpara/f79b561307a56f1c05e1). Thanks